# .Net Google Calendar API - New event has always hangout meets activated

Tags: c#, calendar, google-hangouts, conference

In my .Net test app I run the following code. The new calendar event is successfully created but it has hangout meets conference on the event. How can i disable the automatically creation of an hangout meet conference on the event?

I have tried to set body.ConferenceData = null but it doesn't has any effect.
Using the CalendarService.Events.Patch method after the Insert method is also not working.

It also not possible to assign an existing conference by filling the fields in body.ConferenceData using ConferenceSolution class - its completely ignored and the conference is always created new.

```
        Event body = new Event();
        EventAttendee a = new EventAttendee();
        a.Email = "test@test.de";
        List<EventAttendee> attendes = new List<EventAttendee>();
        attendes.Add(a);
        body.Attendees = attendes;
        EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime();
        start.DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2020-04-14T09:00:00");
        EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime();
        end.DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2020-04-14T11:00:00");
        body.Start = start;
        body.End = end;
        body.Location = "Room";
        body.Summary = "test description";

        Event newEvent = CalendarService.Events.Insert(body, MyCalendarID).Execute();
```

Comment: I couldn't avoid to create it either, nor remove it afterwards. I will investigate this and will come back with my findings.

Comment: have you found out a solution?

Comment: I found one but only for GSuite accounts. Is this your case?

Comment: Yes we have GSuite account

Answer (score 1):

**Only for G Suite accounts**

To disable Meet conferences being automatically Added to any event created from the API:

1. As an Admin, go to `admin.google.com`
2. Go to Apps > G Suite > Settings for Calendar > Sharing Settings
3. Set `Video Calls` to `OFF`

---

**To manually add a conference to your Event:**

> Add conferenceData with an empty Id to generate a new Meet conference when doing an [insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) request:

Request body:

```
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-05-28T09:00:00-07:00"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-05-27T09:00:00-07:00"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "email": "example@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "conferenceData": {
    "conferenceId": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats ok, but what happens if I want to add a hangouts meet conference to my events by c# app?

Comment: You can still do it adding `conferenceData`. I updated my answer.

Comment: How can I send the request body as request in C#?

Comment: You were doing it in your question. Just add `body.ConferenceData`

Comment: I can't change te conference properties of existing events with conference. How can  I change it?

Comment: @RobinLüdtke it seems like you have more questions besides the one you posted. Ask a new question for these two other topics (How to insert an event with conferenceData in C# and How to remove conferenceData from events in c#, for example)