# Remove Google Meet link from Goocle Calendar Event using Google Calendar .Net SDK

Tags: .net, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 .NET Nuget package in my project to create google calendar events. But it automatically adds Google Meet link to the event which i dont want to.

When i create event, notification mails are sent to attendees which includes this string:

Joining info
Join with Google Meet meet.google.com/******

How can i remove Google Meet from my events. I tried to add this ConferenceData property to Event object and set its value to null but still Google meet is visible in Google Calendar Event .

```
     Event calendarEvent = new Event
            {
                ... ,
                ConferenceData = null
            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PHP I am achieving like this:

```
$event_data = array(
        'summary' => $event->getSubject(),
        'location' => $event->getLocation()->getDisplayName(),
        'description' => $html,
        'start' => array(
            'dateTime' => $event->getStart()->getDateTime(),
            'timeZone' => $event->getStart()->getTimeZone(),
        ),
        'end' => array(
            'dateTime' => $event->getEnd()->getDateTime(),
            'timeZone' => $event->getEnd()->getTimeZone(),
        ),
        'reminders' => [
            'useDefault' => true,
        ],
        'attendees' => array(
            array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
            array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
        ),
        'conferenceData' => null,
    );

$google_event_insert = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $google_event, ['conferenceDataVersion' => 1]);
```

From above code, please note, we are sending "conferenceData" as null + adding a query parameter conferenceDataVersion=1 to the insert request.

This works perfectly OK for me. You can use it in similar way in your .net code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using G Suite account you can do as the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61253548/):

> To disable Meet conferences being automatically Added to any event created from the API:
>
> 1. As an Admin, go to `admin.google.com`
> 2. Go to Apps > G Suite > Settings for Calendar > Sharing Settings
> 3. Set `Video Calls` to `OFF`

Also I would suggest you to look at the guide for [Add video and phone conferences to events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events#conferencing).

In there there is some explanation on how to modify events:

> The `conferenceData` field can be used to read, copy, and clear existing conference details; it can also be used to request generation of new conferences. To allow creation and modification of conference details, set the `conferenceDataVersion` request parameter to 1.

Comment: Is there a way to make this programatically, I mean i dont want to disable Google Meets for all events using my Google Suite Account.

I just want to disable google meet for events that are created programatically from my code.

Comment: You can just create the event and then delete it (in this case deleting could mean leave it blank)